# Possible to stay on page and get OK message after file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

If I don't use the JavaScript below, then the page changes after the user have uploaded and clicked Submit. The JavaScript ensures that the page stays.

**Problem**

Using the HTML and JavaScript the page stays, which is what I want, and I get the radio button value. But upload doesn't work any longer.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong since upload doesn't work any more?

When this works, then I would like `<div id="status">Click upload</div>` changes to `<div id="status">Upload complete</div>` if success, in case this changes the solution.

**HTML**

```
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="stuff.js"></script>
</head><body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cgi-bin/test.py" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="red" /> Red
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="green" /> Green
<p>File: <input type="file" name="filename" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
<br/><br/>
<div id="status">Click upload</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something here on success
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: FYI, you can't upload files through ajax

Comment: @Manoz i guess you don't know it yet. you can use `FormData`.

Comment: Yes @Manoz ,there is a plugin available called ajaxFileUpload

Comment: @Jai, `Using XMLHttpRequest` i have done it, let me know if any other way is there? seems like I am outdated!

Comment: @Manoz try with `FormData`.

Comment: @Manoz https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @Jai, yes mate that `XMLHttpRequest` is ideally ajax right?

Comment: The problem was not the sending of data, but the "gathering" of data. In previous versions of HTML4, there was not a way to to pick out the "file" data from the form. Now you can do that using `FormData` as @Jai has mentioned and then send it using ajax (XHR) the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do an ajax file upload with `$.post`, you have to use `$.ajax` (or raw XMLHttpRequest) and a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object. Using a formdata object as the data parameter  in $.ajax requires you to set `contentType` and `processData` to false

```
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('action'), 
          type: $(this).attr('method'), 
          data: new FormData(this), 
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(response){
            // do something here on success
          },
          dataType: 'json'
      });
      return false;
   });
```

Comment: `contentType and processData to false` is the way to go.

Comment: I don't see the file being uploaded. In the old case, was it uploaded to `/tmp`. No errors in webserver log or Firefox debugger.

Comment: @Musa I see the path where the file should be, but it is not uploaded. Please see output here http://pastebin.com/2ySdiyQS Do I have to init the upload somehow?

Comment: Check the the network tab in the firefox debugger to see if the file is being uploaded.